# RDS size discrepancy between data and a subset of the data

Tags: r, dataframe, compression

I am noticing an interesting discrepancy where a smaller data frame has a larger size when I save them out to RDS files. Consider two data frames:

Data Frame A (DFA): Contains 22 variables and 2,000,000 observations

Data Frame B (DFB): A subset of A that remove rows where a gender variable equals female. Additionally, DFA had 3 null filled columns that were discarded, so this data frame contains 19 variables and 1,800,000 observations

So DFB is a subset of columns and a subset of rows of DFA, but the RDS file size for DFA (8.6 MB) is smaller than the size for DFB (11.4 MB).

Why would this be?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `str` for the two data.frames?

Comment: Unfortunately due to some sensitive information I cannot. For reference though, object.size yields 322795160 bytes for DFA and 254357016 bytes for DFB

Comment: Did any of the columns change type? For example did a character column change to factor or the other way around?

Comment: Per str() all column types are the same in both dataframes.